# Is it possible to connect remix and Parity?

Tags: remix, parity

I would like to connect remix to a parity node running on my machine. Even if I am setting up parity with the --rpc or --jsonrpc switch, I cannot connect. Is it even possible? Thanks!

Comment: According to this [link](https://github.com/ethereum/remix/issues/754), Parity doesn't support all required RPC APIs. Is it still the case?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to connect with Remix, you just need to make sure that all required APIs are correctly open, and that your Parity Ethereum node accepts Remix CORS headers.

Using the following configuration for instance in a toml file:

`[rpc]
port = 8545 #default http port for RPC
apis = ["eth","net","private","parity","personal"] 
cors = ["http://remix.ethereum.org"]  # allow remix to access this node`

or directly with CLI flags:
`--jsonrpc-apis "eth","net","private","parity","personal" --jsonrpc-cors "http://remix.ethereum.org"`